# How do I reference the CORS namespace in WebApiConfig.cs?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to add CORS support to a locally hosted web api 2 project following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

I have added the CORS package via the package manager:

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Cors

Next, as described in the tutorial, I have added the following line to my webconfig.cs file:

config.EnableCors();

Intellisense is now showing that I need a reference for the EnableCors call.  I have searched around the web and the latest documentation I can find states that the following reference is required:

using System.Web.Cors;

However, this reference does not resolve the EnableCors call.  Can anyone explain what reference namespace is needed?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE!  I got this problem figured out!  In Nuget, I loaded Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.  The reference in the WebConfig.cs file becomes

using System.Web.Http.Cors;

At the beginning of the webConfig.cs file, add the following lines, changing the URL for your specific situation:

```
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:57357", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

In the tutorial, an attribute is used.  If you wish to use an attribute, then add the call to enable CORS in the WebConfig.cs file, shown here:

config.EnableCors();

I hope this answer provides some guidance to others dealing with this problem.  Happy coding!